# How to interpret a reduced chi squared value

Tags: chi-squared-test

When I make a linear fit, it produces a reduced chi squared value. If it is larger than 1, this means underfitting, and if it is smaller than 1, then it is overfitting. If the value is approximately 1, then it is a good fit. But what is the meaning of `approximately 1'?

What would be the interval that the reduced chi squared value must be in, for which I can say ‘it is a good fit’? This would be an interval like $[0.5,1.5]$.

Comment: You need to know the degrees of freedom.  For that purpose, use the non-reduced chi-squared value.

Comment: What would be a good interval for that?

Comment: The chi-squared distribution tells you.